# Debug this CircleCI / Docker bash error (script not found)?

Tags: node.js, linux, continuous-integration, circleci, ash

I am trying to run a script called `install_chrome.sh` inside a CircleCI build. I'm using [this Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/rickydunlop/nodejs-ffmpeg/). I didn't make the image, it just contains the two dependencies I need (Node and ffmpeg).

The image installs fine via CircleCI, but then the `install_chrome.sh` build step fails. This build step *does not* fail with the CircleCI "standard" NodeJs image, for reference.

Here's my `config.yml`:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/my-project
    docker:
      - image: rickydunlop/nodejs-ffmpeg
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Debug 1
          command: pwd
      - run:
          name: Debug 2
          command: ls
      - run:
          name: Install Chrome
          command: ${HOME}/${CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME}/install_chrome.sh .google-chrome
```

And here's the output:

[image]

What could be going on? Based on those debugs, I am definitely in the right directory, and my source code is definitely sitting there. Is this a user issue? What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `ash`, not `bash`.

`ash` will print "not found" whenever `execve()` returns ENOENT, which can happen for any of the following reasons:

1. The file does not exist
2. The file's interpreter does not exist
3. The file's interpreter's dynamic loader does not exist

Since you've confirmed that the file does exist, look at your script's shebang with:

```
head -n 1 install_chrome.sh
```

and make sure that whichever executable it points to is installed and available at that path.

If you do have it in that path, check that you can execute it separately.